# user-data-dir not working anymore on selenium with chromedriver 90

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

user-data-dir not working anymore on selenium with chromedriver 90

already tried to reinstall chrome, redownload chromedriver and adding:
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

not working on win10 laptop and on win 8.1 laptop

I've not touched anything and yesterday was working. HELP ME PLEASE!

edit: when i try to run my pyhton script on windows 8.1 it says that chrome can't write or read in a directory (i'm italian, it's a translation) but when i run on win10 it says "Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

EDIT2: If you have one single script it works by adding chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9292")

If you have to run more than one change --user-data-dir=profile to --user-data-dir=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\profile

Comment: Not chromedriver but my chrome shortcuts with custom user-data dir stopped working after updating to chrome 90 with the same error message. I fixed that by changing relative path to absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks, but how to?

Comment: Basically, i changed `--user-data-dir=profile` to `--user-data-dir=C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\profile`. But this was for a chrome shortcut and not chromedriver so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Thanks i changed it with the complete path and it worked! In another life i'll buy you a beer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No promises that this will work for you, but my code did the same thing overnight and what fixed it was explicitly setting the remote debugging port:

```
options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9292")
```

Seems to be either a Chrome 90 or Chromedriver issue/feature.

Comment: Thanks god, it seems to works, but i think it's a problem if i want to run more than 1 script and they all have the same remote debugging port... i'll test now but THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Edit: works only on win10, in win8.1 it opens the browser putting the url to remote-debugging-port%3D9292